# Connect mongodb v5 to nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, version, new-operator

How to connect new mongodb v5 to nodejs

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);
async function main() {
    await client.connect();
}
const collection = client.db('internfeb').collection('dashboard');
const port = process.env.PORT || 7710;

app.get('/health',async(req,res) => {
    const output = []
    const cursor = collection.find({});
        for await (const doc of cursor) {
        output.push(doc)
    }
    cursor.closed; 
    res.send(output)
})


app.post('/addUser',async(req,res) => {
    await collection.insertOne(req.body)
    res.send('Data Added')
})

app.listen(port,() => {
    main()
    console.log(`Running on thr port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: which issue are you facing?

Comment: There is no issue i am just helping people with new syntax its a working code

Comment: great, good to go